# Does the sony slt a35 have an in body focus motor?

Tags: autofocus, sony, focus-motor, slt

Does the sony slt a35 have an in body focus motor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the SLT a35 has a focus motor in the body. You can use legacy A-mount lenses, such as Minolta lenses since 1986, and non-SAM (Smooth Autofocus Motor) and non-SSM (Super Sonic wave Motor) lenses on the SLT a35.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I searched a lot of reviews and specifications on the net like imaging resource's, dpreview but none of them have a clear answer

Comment: Most reviews of the a35 only talk about autofocus performance of the kit lens and body combo